# Validate and filter email address with RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email-validation

What's the best way to disallow free email service emails (e.g. Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail) using RegEx and Javascript email field validation?

```
^.*@(?!(aol\.com$|yahoo\.com$|hotmail\.com$))$
```

I've seen the generic "Validate email address in Javascript" solution here [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript/46181#46181) but cant figure out how to make it disallow Gmail, Yahoo and Hotmail.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b
```

Comment: Do you have to use regular expressions? Could you instead just split on the `@` and then compare to a blacklist of TLDs?

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party form framework that allows regular expressions for custom validation.  Therefore, I have to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 8):

One of thousands of acceptable ways to get there - not that yours isn't acceptable...

```
function isGoodEmail(email) {
    if(isValidEmail(email)) {
        if(/(aol|gmail|yahoo|hotmail)\.com$/.test(email)) {
           alert(' valid email, but not for this site.  No free service emails!');
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isValidEmail(email) {
  // implement using any of the email regexp's available 
}
```

Comment: I have to use regular expressions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I will make sure to edit the question.