# Script to not allow to enter personal email address

Tags: javascript

```
var str=document.validation.emailcheck.value
var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
```

I have the following script. I need a script that does not allow users to enter their personal email address such as gmail,yahoo,hotmail, etc.

Comment: so... what's the problem, exactly? Apart from you wanting someone to do it for you.

Comment: Be careful doing this. Are you sure you never want Yahoo or Google to be one of your clients? I used to think it unlikely until a rep from Google contacted my boss about our product.

Comment: possible duplicate- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083937/validate-and-filter-email-address-with-regex

Comment: @sachleen I am new to java script I think this has been used bysome one already..Any suggestions to imporve java script

Comment: @ManojChowdary - Use a regex to check if any of the `google,yahoo` exist in the domain of the email address.

Comment: @slebetman Yeah I need this functionality to be done

Comment: @Manoj Chowdary - how to improve? Sit down, read, read a lot, and then show some efforts. Only after that ask.

Answer (score 3):

There is no script that can reliably block *every single* personal email address out there.
The variety of email providers is just too large.

Now, technically, you could build a "blacklist" of disallowed domains in the email, like:

```
var blocked = ["google", "yahoo", "hotmail", "etc"];
```

And then check if the email address contains any of those, but that would also block anyone working for those companies.

The real question is why you'd want to do this.